# Spark SQL Pyspark update value in table to another value in table

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that I can query with SQL. There are two columns one is called Actor1Type1 and the other is called Actor2Type1. If a cell in column Actor1Type1 is '' and Actor2Type1 is not '', then I want to change the value of that cell to the value of Actor2Type1. I have no idea how to do this with Spark SQL because I am new to it.

So far I have

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, 'temp')
new_df = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT CASE WHEN temp.Actor1Type1Code == '' AND temp.Actor2Type1Code != ''
                    THEN temp.Actor1Type1Code""")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to assign the value of Actor2Type1 to Actor1Type1 when `Actor1Type1 == '' AND Actor2Type1 != ''`

Here is how you do it,

```
df2 = sqlContext.sql('select (case when Actor1Type1 == '' AND Actor2Type1 != '' then Actor2Type1 else Actor1Type1 end) as Actor1Type1,Actor2Type1 from temp')
```